# Where to find VNC access logs with IP addresses on Sierra?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, logs, network

I'm looking for logs on attempts by someone to access one of my Macs on a previous day. I have remote management running and I allow VNC access. In the logs I have found, I see the attempts they made, but there's no IP address logged. Where can I see this?

An example of a console log I have is "system.log.0" (backed up the last day). I have tons of these log events from when someone was connected:

> (com.apple.screensharing[2323232]): Endpoint has been activated through legacy launch (3) API's

There is no other logged info.

Also, I don't have a "secure.log" file.

I just want to know what IPs were connected to my Mac during a specific time frame. Is there any other log or source of info in macOS Sierra I could harvest for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've found any solutions, but I've began combing through this https://www.mac4n6.com/blog/2016/11/13/new-macos-sierra-1012-forensic-artifacts-introducing-unified-logging but haven't had the time to figure out how to log / monitor VNC connections

Answer (score 10):

Beginning with macOS Sierra, there is a new unified logging system, which requires a bit more work to access than the old system.log, but includes far more details.

Use this command to show the last three days of access logs:
`log show --last 3d --predicate 'processImagePath CONTAINS "screensharingd" AND eventMessage CONTAINS "Authentication"'`

This will show timestamps, IP, username, and authentication failure/success for both VNC and Apple Screen Sharing connections.

Comment: This is great...thanks for sharing the command. How can we make it persistent and have it log this in Console? Is there another log maintaining this I can't see?

Comment: What do you mean by persistent? The console app is nearly useless in Sierra. To show in real-time you can use `log stream` instead.

Comment: More info about Console: https://eclecticlight.co/2016/09/23/sierras-console-promising-but-incomplete/

Comment: I mean see a backfilled log the console keeps. I want to see log records in the console

Comment: Can this be adapted to show ssh connections?

Comment: Certainly. You just need to find the right predicate

Comment: How can you remove VNC logs out of the log and where is the actual file ?

Comment: @Kevin I'm not aware of any way to remove entries. The files are tracev3 compressed binary format in `/var/db/diagnostics` so you could delete the whole thing.