# Is there a log somewhere that will show when I have done screensharing?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, logs, screen-sharing

Over the past week, I have been doing a lot of remote access using the Screen Sharing.app. Is there a place that logs when I have used it and for how long? I've looked in the Console.app but haven't found anything useful when I search for screensharing.

Comment: So you use screensharing on your Mac and you want to know when it connected out to other devices?

Comment: Yes, correct. I was hoping my mac was logging those connections somewhere.

Comment: See if this helps:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283385/119271  I don't want to flag as a dupe yet because I can close with one vote.  If it works, you can flag as a dupe