# Has something changed in Ventura/recent version of MacOS with respect to ssh tunnels? Can't tunnel VNC nor SMB despite SSH working as expected

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, smb, ventura, tunnel

I connect ssh like this:

```
% ssh -L 1445:127.0.0.1:445 -L 15900:127.0.0.1:5900 -p 2216 -v myhost
```

Excerpt from the verbose log when connecting:

```
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:1445 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:445
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 1445.
debug1: channel 0: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 1445.
debug1: channel 1: new [port listener]
debug1: Local connections to LOCALHOST:15900 forwarded to remote address 127.0.0.1:5900
debug1: Local forwarding listening on ::1 port 15900.
debug1: channel 2: new [port listener]
debug1: Local forwarding listening on 127.0.0.1 port 15900.
debug1: channel 3: new [port listener]
debug1: channel 4: new [client-session]
```

…

```
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
```

(no corresponding line for SMB/445)

When I then try to connect VNC using this (from the command line)

```
open vnc://127.0.0.1:15900
```

the connection dialogue appears but after I enter my details it just "shakes" (no error message or anything).

For SMB I use a similar URL

open smb://127.0.0.1:1445

Here I at least get an error message that a problem occurred and that I should contact the admin. Both VNC and SMB works when I connect directly when I am on the LAN, and I used to do this frequently some years ago.

A verbose ssh log from a VNC-attempt:

```
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
debug1: channel 6: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 5: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 15900 for 127.0.0.1 port 5900, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51566 to 127.0.0.1 port 15900, nchannels 7
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 6: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 15900 for 127.0.0.1 port 5900, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51567 to 127.0.0.1 port 15900, nchannels 7
debug1: channel 5: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 15900 for 127.0.0.1 port 5900, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51569 to 127.0.0.1 port 15900, nchannels 6
```

and for SMB:

```
debug1: Connection to port 1445 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 445 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 5: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 1445 for 127.0.0.1 port 445, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51578 to 127.0.0.1 port 1445, nchannels 6
```

One odd detail is that, for VNC, I have two users on the destination machine, A and B. A is my main user and the user I am logged in as when I try to tunnel VNC over SSH and fail, **BUT** if I instead try to login as B over VNC (while A is logged in locally), the connection works. An SSH-log from such a login:

```
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
debug1: channel 6: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 5: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 15900 for 127.0.0.1 port 5900, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51642 to 127.0.0.1 port 15900, nchannels 7
debug1: Connection to port 15900 forwarding to 127.0.0.1 port 5900 requested.
debug1: channel 5: new [direct-tcpip]
debug1: channel 6: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 15900 for 127.0.0.1 port 5900, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 51643 to 127.0.0.1 port 15900, nchannels 7
```

Trying to login as B over SMB yields the same error message as A sees.

I have three computers and I have the same problem with all of them. I use ssh-keys with https://www.funtoo.org/Funtoo:Keychain. If I tunnel over my LAN I get the same result. Feels like something has changed in recent versions of MacOS?

An odd detail is that I, when I SSH over internet, need to ctrl-c to exit the connection. That is, after I enter `exit` to logout something gets stuck in the logout process. It is not until I send a ctrl-c that it finishes and I am returned to my local shell. This does not happen when I SSH on the LAN, in that case I just enter exit and the connection is stopped as expected.

---

Update:

Here is a log from a failed, tunneled, VNC-login according to the instructions in a comment:

```
2023-08-18 08:52:05.095119+0200 0xe3cc3b   Default     0x0                  98235  0    screensharingd: SendAuthenticationInfoMessage
2023-08-18 08:52:05.126178+0200 0xe3cc3b   Default     0x0                  98235  0    screensharingd: HandleViewerAuthenticationMessages 2
2023-08-18 08:52:05.126193+0200 0xe3cc3b   Default     0x0                  98235  0    screensharingd: SendRSAResponseSRPAuthentication
2023-08-18 08:52:05.306678+0200 0xe3cc3b   Default     0x0                  98235  0    screensharingd: HandleViewerAuthenticationMessages 10
2023-08-18 08:52:05.306684+0200 0xe3cc3b   Default     0x0                  98235  0    screensharingd: SendRSAResponseSRPAuthentication
```

and here a successful login (not tunneled):

```
2023-08-18 08:47:05.720064+0200 0xe3b74b   Default     0x0                  97627  0    screensharingd: HandleViewerAuthenticationMessages 2
2023-08-18 08:47:05.720072+0200 0xe3b74b   Default     0x0                  97627  0    screensharingd: HandleViewerAuthenticationMessages 7
2023-08-18 08:47:06.058599+0200 0xe3b74b   Default     0x0                  97627  0    screensharingd: HandleViewerAuthenticationMessages 7
2023-08-18 08:47:06.375293+0200 0xe3b4d8   Default     0x0                  97627  0    screensharingd: Authentication: SUCCEEDED :: User Name: db :: Viewer Address: 192.168.1.13 :: Type: Kerberos
```

Can't see anything obvious that is wrong/different here?

Comment: There's nothing specifically Apple about SSH.  They are using OpenSSH.  Type `ssh -V` to get the current version installed.  I'm on Ventura 13.5, with OpenSSH v9.01p1 with no tunnel issues.

Comment: @Allan OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6 - so what do you think is wrong for me?

Comment: I missed the line where you say the login dialog "shakes."  That indicates authentication failed.  I would be curios to see the Mac's VNC authentication log entries.  See [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/326994/119271) for how to do this.  You might want to just try connecting again just to have recent entries rather than searching for them.

Comment: @Allan Updated with the requested logs. What gives?

Comment: The good news is messages are being sent through the tunnel indicated by the  messages responses.  However, it doesn't like the authentication for some reason.  Are you on a corporate network by any change?  The Kerberos authentication jumps out at me.

Comment: @Allan Nope, everything here is my own private hardware.

Comment: @Allan But in the case of VNC, using my secondary user account (which I use for test, debugging etc), the connection works.

Comment: Does your secondary user work if you try this remotely?

Comment: @Allan Yes. I haven't done extensive testing but if my main user A is logged in but the screen is locked and B, my extra user, is not logged in and I open a tunnel and try to log in as B I get this question "Do you want watch A's screen or request to use the screen as B" or something along those lines.